# jQuery Mobile file usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Something was pointed out to me that I never heard of before and came as quite of surprise to me: the files to include when using jQuery Mobile and a custom theme.

As their site states, if you just want to use the bare-bones version of jQuery Mobile, all you need to include is `jquerymobile.css`, `jquery.js`, and `jquerymobile.js`. But what was pointed out to me is that if you want to use a custom theme, you do not have to include `jquerymobile.css` in your header. Just `theme.css` and `mobilestructure.css`.

Is this true or just some confusion on my part? It seems like a simple question but I couldn't find a definitive answer out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is true, I just looked at my code that works using jquerymobile and a theme I made using the theme roller and the only two css files I have are .

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/themes/cyan1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
```